# Dropdown not appearing on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a dropdown menu so when the page is viewed on mobile the user can click and access all the pages available. I am not getting any type of error code, just no response. Below are the snippets of HTML, CSS and JavaScript that should be affecting the code. Thanks for taking the time to read through this.

```js
/*When user clicks name on shows dropdown menu allowing for nav on smaller viewports */
function dropDown() {
  document.getElementById("dropNav").classList.toggle("show");
}

//close drop down if clicked outside
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: white;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* menu below button*/

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* hidden dropdown, using z to plac in front of other elements */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: goldenrod
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="dropDown()" class="dropbtn"><b>AH</b>NAME</button>
  <div id="dropNav" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="index2.html">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="Travels.html">Travels</a>
    <a href="webSecurity.html">Web Security Information</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `console.log("text")` to your code to find out what's happening. If you do that, you find out that the class is added, then immediately removed again. The reason: `!event.target.matches('dropbtn')` is missing the class dot: `!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')`

Comment: @Chris G thanks for the tip. I hadn't thought to do that and I should know better by now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*When user clicks name on shows dropdown menu allowing for nav on smaller viewports */
function dropDown(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  document.getElementById("dropNav").classList.toggle("show");
}

//close drop down if clicked outside
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: white;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* menu below button*/

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* hidden dropdown, using z to plac in front of other elements */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: goldenrod
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="dropDown(event)" class="dropbtn"><b>AH</b>NAME</button>
  <div id="dropNav" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="index2.html">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="Travels.html">Travels</a>
    <a href="webSecurity.html">Web Security Information</a>
  </div>
</div>
```